# How can I qualify or hold to a higher precedence a method not provided by a trait?

Tags: rust, traits, fully-qualified-naming, qualified-name

I have an Add implementation that looks like this,

```rust
impl<T: Into<u64>> Add<T> for Sequence {
  type Output = Self;
  fn add(self, rhs: T) -> Self::Output { 
    let mut o = self.clone();
    o.myadd(rhs.into()).unwrap();
    o 
  } 
}
```

The function `myadd` returns a Result; **This actually works fine.** The problem is in the real world the method is `Sequence.add()` implemented on Sequence that I want the Add to call. If I rename `myadd` to `add` like this,

```rust
o.add(rhs.into()).unwrap();
```

Then it no longer compiles I get instead *"error[E0599]: no method named `unwrap` found for struct `sequence::Sequence` in the current scope"* which tells me that the `add` it's finding is not returning a Result, it's returning a Sequence which is not what I want. How can I qualify the trait in the call to add?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to target add that I supplied under `impl Sequence {}` with the following,

```
Sequence::add(r, rhs.into()).unwrap();
```

You can also use

```
Self::add(r, rhs.into()).unwrap();
```

Comment: Yeah I'm not sure there is an other solution. `Self::add` would also work but amounts to the same thing.

Comment: @Masklinn thanks, I incorporated that into that answer.